# What is the difference between using is with a specific type and var?

Tags: c#, var

What is the difference between these 2 code snippets? One with the `var` works but the one with the type string gives an error.(use of unassigned variable error) Aren't they both unassigned until runtime? I am quite confused about how and where these variables get assigned. Struggling with making a distinction between runtime and compile time calculations.
1st code:

```
 object x = "Message";
 bool result = x is string o;
 Console.WriteLine(o);
```

2nd code:

```
 object x = "Message";
 bool result = x is var o;
 Console.WriteLine(o);
```

2nd one works, 1st one gives the mistake I have mentioned before.

Comment: `var` is a keyword, not a type

Comment: In the first example, `string o` is `null` (unassigned) because `object x` is not a `string`. In the second example, `var o` is referentially equivalent to `object x` because `var` is implicitly typed as `object`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(<unassigned>)` is invalid (as all accesses of an unassigned variable are), so the first example fails. `Console.WriteLine(object)` is valid, so the second example works.

Comment: In the first example, `o` will only ever be assigned if `x` is a `string`.  In the second example, `o` will only ever be assigned if `x` is literally anything, so it will always be assigned.

Comment: Your IDE should warn you about a potential access of an unassigned variable on the line `Console.WriteLine(o)` and suggest that either you assign it (`o = new(); Console.WriteLine(o);`) or check that it is assigned (`if (result) { Console.WriteLine(o); }`).

Comment: Specifically, your IDE is warning you about the first case because it's possible that `string o` is unassigned. As David points out, there's no need for the warning in the second case because `is var o` will always succeed (you might however see warnings about nullablility if you have nullable contexts on).

Comment: Note that the first works if used in an expression (e.g., [`if (x is string o) { Console.WriteLine(o); }`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qjB5Cj))

Comment: @DM it is not possible for `string o` to be unassigned in this code, the `is` check can be statically verified to be always true. What it actually means is that the compiler is not able to detect such simple case, which is weird to be honest.

Comment: @freakish It's definitely unassigned. It's equivalent to writing `string o; Console.WriteLine(o);`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/df7Gwz I agree that it could be statically determined that `object x = "Message"` could be implicitly cast to `string x = "Message"`, but the `is` keyword doesn't consider conversions from `object` to `string` (though the reverse would work): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#:~:text=The%20is%20operator%20returns%20true,result%20to%20type%20T.

Comment: @freakish `is string o` isn't a type check, it's a pattern match expression that assigns `x` to `o` only if it matches. It's equivalent to `string o; if (x is string){ o=x;}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exactly, and this condition is always true. Hence `o` is not undefined. This can be deduced at compile time.

Comment: @freakish wrong, it's only known at runtime. `x` is an *object variable*, not a string or a constant. The compiler doesn't know what value will be stored in there.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the value is literally there one line earlier, what do you mean it doesn't know? The value can't change in the meantime, it is impossible. The real type is fully deducible at compile time.

Comment: No it's not. That's a runtime assignment to an object variable. The only type information known at compilation is that `x` is an object. That's why you can't use string methods on it like eg `x.Substring()`. A reference to the interred string value `"Message"` will be assigned to that variable at runtime. If the code changed to `var x="Message";`, the type would be inferred as `string`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the assignment operation is fully deterministic at compile time, it cannot be overloaded. I really don't get what you are saying. How can this code ever produce a non-expected result? Just because something happens at runtime is irrelevant, if it can be optimized at compile time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That makes sense but if the assignment is done at the run-time, how does do 2nd code with var works and does not give an unassigned variable error?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not to mention that following your line of reasoning `string o; if (true) { o = ""; } Console.WriteLine(o);` should fail, yes? But it compiles without any problems.

Comment: If it helps any of you; when I debugged the one with var, x is initially set as object{string} but o is set as just object. After the execution of the 2nd line it reassigned o to object{string}.

Comment: The compiler simply doesn't yet know whether something will actually end up in `o` or not. Hence the error. It will be a different scenario if you do `object x = 10`, but the compiler doesn't know that. Which explains that `o` is possibly never assigned

Comment: @freakish and yet, the compiler complains. You can argue the compiler is wrong and should be able to guess what the runtime will produce, or try to understand how it works. The compiler *doesn't* know whether the `object x` variable will hold an int, Person or string until runtime. That's because `object x="Message"` *removed* the type information. There's no `if(true)`involved. Could the compiler know? Possibly, if it executed the code. That would generate a WTF situation though that contradicts what the developer explicitly wrote.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I completely disagree with you. There's no technical way in the code above for `x` to hold anything different than the string. You claim that this information is removed, but it is not true. It literalyl is there one line earlier. Its a similar situation to devirtualization, where some information is also "removed" yet the compiler is able to deduce it.

Comment: @freakish that's like arguing the sun rises from the north. It doesn't matter whether you agree or not, the compiler works the way it does. You already see the compiler complains. You argue it doesn't when it actually does. You can argue it *shouldn't*, which is another matter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, the compiler complains because it is not smart enough. That's literally what I said in my first comment.

Comment: So there is a technical reason, you just don't know what it is. If you really care to know, you can go to the csharplang repository where you'll find the discussions on various features *and* the reasons they work the way they do. That includes optimizations like this one that were kept out because they would break existing code, increase complexity or because there was no time to complete. If that's the only problem, the restriction may be relaxed in the future

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, just because compiler is not smart enough doesn't mean there is a real obstacle. Again: the C# standard guarantees that in the code above `x` always is a string, and nothing can change this. Just because a compiler doesn't see it, it doesn't mean such deduction is impossible. Compilers are not alphas and omegas.

Comment: One obstacle is that the compiler would behave in a completely unexpected way, reversing the code's intent. Even though the developer chose to remove the type information with `object x`, the compiler ignored the code and used `string x` instead. If you really care, you can find out at csharplang.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, devolpers "chose" all the time to do things. Like they chose to use virtualization. Should compiler ignore the fact that it can devirtualize things just because a developer made such "choice"? Come on, that's literally what all compilers do all the time: fix bad code and make it as good as they can. It is called optimization.